# PVC's cost report in GCP Billing service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing, kubernetes-pvc

Weeks ago I removed a large amount of PVCs in different GCP projects from my account and I want to reflect that removal tasks in some reports using the billing service in GCP.

Is there a way to select PVCs on the Services/SKUs tabs in the report tool?

I know how to use it for other services but I can't figure out how to do it with PVCs.

Comment: It will show as regular persistent disk, the same as normal VM disks. I think there's some kubernetes label on the disk, maybe you can use to filter.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting here my findings in case to someone else helps this information.

As Hitobat mentioned, On-Demand Persistent Disk SSD and On-Demand Balanced Persistent Disk are the kind of disk used for PVCs on kubernetes environments.

The full list of GCP SKUs can be find here: [SKU Groups](https://cloud.google.com/skus/sku-groups), for specific On-Demand Persistent Disk SSD take a look to [SKU Groups - On-Demand Persistent Disk SSD](https://cloud.google.com/skus/sku-groups/on-demand-persistent-disk-ssd) and for On-Demand Balanced Persistent Disk look
[SKU Groups - On-Demand Balanced Persistent Disk](https://cloud.google.com/skus/sku-groups/on-demand-balanced-persistent-disk)

Remember that SKUs can differ per region.